# Can't add user into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a 3 tables are employee , chief , technician.

So , Admin can add all the user to system but i can't add 'chief' into the table and this is my html.

```
               <form name="form" method="post" action="add_user_db.php">
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label>Type of User</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <select class="form-control" name="filter" id="filter">
                        <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                        <option value="technician">Technician</option>
                        <option value="chief">Chief</option>
                      </select>...some other code..</form>
```

This is my php to add user.

```
$filter = $_POST["filter"];     
    $id = $_POST["id"]; 
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $department = $_POST["department"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $cellphone = $_POST["cellphone"];


    if($filter =='chief'){
    $sql = "INSERT into $filter (chief_id,password,chief_name,status,department,phone,cellphone,email) values ('$id', '$password', '$name', 'CHIEF', '$department', '$phone', '$cellphone', '$email')"; 
    $dbquery = mysql_db_query("inform_db", $sql);

    mysql_close();
    header( "refresh:0.01;url=add_user.php" );

}
    if($filter == 'employee'){
    $sql = "INSERT into $filter (employee_id,password,name,status,department,phone,cellphone,email) values  ('$id', '$password', '$name', 'USER', '$department', '$phone', '$cellphone', '$email')"; 
    $dbquery = mysql_db_query("inform_db", $sql);

    mysql_close();
    header( "refresh:0.01;url=add_user.php" );

}
    if($filter == 'technician'){
    $sql = "INSERT into $filter (tech_id,password,tech_name,status,phone,cellphone,email) values  ('$id', '$password', '$name', 'TECH', '$phone', '$cellphone', '$email')";
    $dbquery = mysql_db_query("inform_db", $sql);
```

I can't understand why 'chief' especially.

Answer (score 0):

`status` is MySQL KEYWORD. So I just added back tick (`) in query.

Change from

```
$sql = "INSERT into $filter (chief_id,password,chief_name,status,department,phone,cellphone,email) values ('$id', '$password', '$name', 'CHIEF', '$department', '$phone', '$cellphone', '$email')";
```

To

```
$sql = "INSERT into $filter (chief_id,password,chief_name,`status`,department,phone,cellphone,email) values ('$id', '$password', '$name', 'CHIEF', '$department', '$phone', '$cellphone', '$email')";
```

Comment: I following your way but it just the same , All the table can add but not 'chief' especially.

Comment: it not happened error anything. i don't understand , but just can't add 'chief' user to mysql.